# Loop IF statement through every column

Tags: vba, excel

I downloaded survey results and put them into Excel.

I can apply this macro to "A" column.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

counter = 2 'moves output

For Each n In [A7:A50]  'loops through cell in specified range

    If n < 400 Then
        Sheets("Output").Cells(counter, "B") = 0 'Output to other sheet, = points awarded
    ElseIf n > 400 Then
        Sheets("Output").Cells(counter, "B") = 3 'Output to other seet, = points awarded
    End If

    counter = counter + 1 'moves counter up 1

Next

End Sub
```

"B-R" all have the same conditions as "A" Column. Instead of typing this code

```
Sheets("Output").Cells(counter, "B") = 3 'Output to other seet, = points awarded
```

over and over with just switching "A" and the output column, is it possible to loop my counter and my if statement.

My script looks at column/rows A7:A50 in "Results Worksheet", produces points in Column B of the "Output Worksheet."

I haven't been able to make it look at Column B (results worksheet) then output to Column C in (output worksheet), then look at Column C (results worksheet), then output to column D (output worksheet).

Comment: Look at nested loops (For...For...Next...Next) - one for columns and one for rows and set both values of Cells() based on your loop counters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set rng = Range("A:R") ' define your range

For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count ' loop through the columns

    counter = 2 'moves output

    For Each n In Range(Cells(7, i), Cells(50, i)) 'loops through cell in specified column i 

    If n < 400 Then
        Sheets("Output").Cells(counter, i + 1) = 0 'Output to other sheet, = points awarded
    ElseIf n > 400 Then
        Sheets("Output").Cells(counter, i + 1) = 3 'Output to other seet, = points awarded


    End If

    counter = counter + 1 'moves counter up 1

    Next
Next i

End Sub
```

I have added a loop that goes through each column in Range A:R and applies  your macro for each of the column. I have replaced the "B" in the if statements so the results will  be applied to desired column:

evaluate column "A" -> update column "B",

evaluate column "B" -> update column "C"...

Does this help?

Comment: Hello, this appears to have worked the best, thank you so much. I've only been working with VBA for a couple days and could only get so far as the original post.

Comment: No problem, i'm a beginner as well so i know the struggle. Happy i could help :)

Comment: What resource have you used? My next step I am trying to expand this macro into a different variable, so basically after R, S-AB, becomes a new type of question and I must change the iF statement.

Comment: Actually wrote this myself. There are 2 ways to expand this: 

1) For the next set of columns you could just copy this block of code and change the `rng = Range("A:R")` to `rng = Range("S:AB")`, the `For i = i To rng.Columns.Count` to `For i = 18 To rng.Columns.Count + 18` and alter the IF statement as needed. 

2) You could extend the rng to  `rng = Range("A:AB")` and put an additional IF statement to check the value of `i `.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, I am having trouble again, this time the If statement is not picking up the text answers of "True" or "False." it is automatically defaulting to false. I've tried to delimit/clear formats, still no luck. When I try to enter the IF statement as a normal excel equation in the worksheet, it works.

Comment: I'll only post the IF statement 

`If n = "Manufacturing" Then
        Sheets("Output").Cells(counter, i + 6) = Worksheets("Points").Range("D2") 'Output to other sheet, = points awarded
    ElseIf n <> "Manufacturing" Then
        Sheets("Output").Cells(counter, i + 6) = Worksheets("Points").Range("E2") 'Output to other sheet, = points awarded`

Comment: Run the code step by step and check the values of `n`. I would also check the `n.address` to make sure it responds to correct cells. I have checked the statements and it worked well.

Comment: Don't think it is catching the right column, went ahead and put an error message box, without, the code produces 0's, now with the error box message, I run it and an error occurs. Going to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer to hopefully solve your issue. There are a few things I see.

First, I believe that you need to activate each sheet before your result goes in. Second, use .value after identifying which cell you want the output to go into. Third the Cells() function uses integers, so "B" should be 2.

Try using the below code and see if that works for you.

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim r as Long
    Dim c as Long
    Dim lastrow as Integer
    Dim lastcol as Integer
    Dim cpath as String

    cpath = Worksheets("SHEETNAME") 'less typing later on
    cpath2 = Worksheets("Output")
    lastrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    lstcolm = WorksheetFunction.CountA(cpath.Rows(1).EntireRow)
    cpath.Cells(2,1).Activate   'assuming you have a header row


    For c = 1 to lastcol
    For r = 2 to lastrow

If cpath.cells(r,c).value < 400 Then

cpath2.Activate
    cpath2.Cells(r, 2).value = 0
ElseIf n > 400 Then

cpath2.Activate
    cpath2.Cells(r, 2).value = 3
End If

cpath.activate

next r
next c 

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting used to the formatting for this site.. &lt and &gt for the win.